# How to manipulate a query for 'Average Session Duration' to 'Average Session Duration by DAU' using Google Analytics in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I currently have a query that returns 'Average Session Duration Across Platforms.' I need it to now return 'Average Session Duration by DAU Across Platforms.' The difference between the three tables below is iOS, Android and web data. `user_id` is a custom dimension we have in GA that I could use, but adding this alone is not going to get me the results I am looking for. I think I need to add the user_id custom dimension and do something with the date, to get unique users by date. However, I am new to using BigQuery and am unable to do this on my own. I realize this ask is vague - happy to update my question accordingly.

```
WITH
  base AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      _TABLE_SUFFIX AS table_date,
      "web" AS app_source,
      *
    FROM
      `XXXX.ga_sessions_*`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      _TABLE_SUFFIX AS table_date,
      "iOS" AS app_source,
      *
    FROM
      `XXXX.ga_sessions_*`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      _TABLE_SUFFIX AS table_date,
      "Android" AS app_source,
      *
    FROM
      `XXXX.ga_sessions_*` )
  WHERE
    NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(table_date, "intraday|backup") )
SELECT
  FORMAT_DATE("%E4Y-%m-01", PARSE_DATE("%E4Y%m%d", MIN(table_date))) AS
ymd,
  AVG(COALESCE(totals.timeOnSite, totals.timeOnScreen, 0)) as timeOnSite
 FROM
  base
WHERE
  table_date > "20180101"
  GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: so you want average time for every user on each platform by date? right?

Comment: A useful way of reformulating the question is in terms of the dimensions and measures you want; roughly, you want a table whose first column cuts up all the data into `DAUs`, and you want the next column to be Avg. Session Duration. I'm not sure what Daily Active Users looks like as a dimension – what values does that first column show? Do you want it to show cohorts? Or do you only want Avg Session Duration for *today's* DAUs?

Comment: @jagthebeetle Daily Active Users would be a sum of user_id, the average session duration would be in seconds or minutes and date would have more than just today, i.e. all of 2019 day by day.

Comment: @khan I would like average session duration across all users (rather than per every user) on each platform by date. Per every user would work, too, but is not needed.

Comment: I added an answer which may help. Also, please make sure to use single quotes for encapsulating strings in SQL syntax.

Comment: Also, it seems like you are picking from the same table three times and unionizing the results without any filtering in each of the selects. Isn't a `where` condition needed in each of those unionized selects, in order to get the respective platform data?

Comment: @khan it is actually three different tables and the difference is iOS, Android and web. The 'xxxx' is in place of the actual table name for each. The `where` condition is at the bottom of the query I provided.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need aggregation on both levels then. Does this help?

```
WITH base AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      _TABLE_SUFFIX AS table_date,
      'web' AS app_source,
      *
    FROM
      `XXXX.ga_sessions_*`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      _TABLE_SUFFIX AS table_date,
      'iOS' AS app_source,
      *
    FROM
      `XXXX.ga_sessions_*`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      _TABLE_SUFFIX AS table_date,
      'Android' AS app_source,
      *
    FROM
      `XXXX.ga_sessions_*` 
  )
  WHERE NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(table_date, 'intraday|backup') 
)

select 
   app_source,
   parse_date('%Y%m%d', table_date) as date,
   count(distinct user_id) as total_users,
   AVG(coalesce(totals.timeOnSite, totals.timeOnScreen, 0)) as average_time_on_site
from base
group by 1,2
order by 1,2
```

Comment: This definitely helps. Let me try this and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: If it helped, please mark the answer as correct. Thanks.

Comment: Would I need to add the custom dimension `user_id` somewhere in the query in order to be able to count it in the last select statement?